# Return the contents of a template from a custom Twig function in a module?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, modules

I have a template that outputs some JSON formatted data.

I've built a simple module that needs to get the contents of that template, decode the JSON data, and return it.

I believe I need to use `craft()->templates->render('path/to/template')`, but when I do, I get:

`Call to undefined function modules\importjsonmodule\twigextensions\craft()`

The only explanation I can think of is that `craft()` cannot be used in a module in the way it can in a plugin. Is that the case? If so, is there any way I can access the Templates service from within a module?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `craft()` function in Craft 3 and there are no Modules in Craft 2.
You probably mix the two different versions.

#### Craft 3

```
Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('/path/to/template');
```

Of course you need to be in the correct namespace. You have to either `use Craft` or do `\Craft`

#### Craft 2

```
craft()->templates->render('path/to/template')
```

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks @RobinSchambach. My problem now is that `Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate` appears to be setting the Content-Type header to `application/json`. So when I use the Twig function in a Twig template, it's trying to render the template as JSON rather than HTML.  I don't suppose you know how I can stop it from doing that?

Comment: No. The function does not change the response type at all and it does not change the headers either. When you call the function inside a template it returns normal html - like everywhere else. The response object in your Controller is responsible for the headers. If you are going to return JSON in your controller you have to to `return $this->asJson($data)` if not, do `return $this->renderTemplate()`

Comment: OK thanks @Robin. My module doesn't currently have a controller; just the main module class and the twig extension class. I think I'll need to learn a bit more about how modules work! If you don't mind, in the context of `return $this->asJson($data)`, what is `$this`?

Comment: `$this` is the controller that is responsible for the request. I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to return json in a Twig function just decode it like you are used to in PHP, if not return the html

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom twig function that gets JSON data from a template, then returns that data in a way that it can be used in the template where the twig function has been used. For example, in my HTML template, I could do `{% set data = importJSON('path/to/template') %} {{ data.something }} {{ data.somethingElse }}` where `importJSON()` is my custom twig function.

Comment: That's usually a really bad idea and bad practice as well because Twig is used to be a template engine and not meant to be abused in that way. In general templates produce HTML and no JSON, you **can** do it but I would not recommend so. However - you could do `$html = Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate($path); return json_encode($html);` But you will have to `json_decode` your string in Twig... not sure what this should be good for

Comment: OK, maybe I'll have to have a rethink. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you create the data you want to return in PHP and return an Object from the beginning?

Comment: I'm actually just thinking the same thing. I originally wanted the data available as JSON so I could access it from JavaScript as well, but actually that might not be a requirement anymore.

Comment: If that's the case just do `var json = {{ yourObject|json_encode|raw }}`

Comment: Yeah, good idea.  OK I think I have enough to make this work. Thanks for your help, I really appeciate it!